# SPARK SQL using Java Can't apply date filter on dataset/dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using SPARK SQL and Java8. I am having trouble applying date filter on data frame / dataset.

```
final String dbTable = "tablea";
Dataset<Row> jdbcDF =  sparkSession.read().jdbc(connectionURL, dbTable, "GENERATED_ID", 10001, 499999, 1, connectionProperties);

jdbcDF.createOrReplaceTempView("new_perf_returns");

Dataset<Row> sqlDF = sparkSession.sql("select * from new_perf_returns where code= 'YYZ' and row_type = 0");

Dataset<Row> df = sqlDF.filter("as_of = date_format('2017-01-25','yyyy-MM-dd')");
```

I get this error  `java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`

I have also tried applying filter in sql also like this

```
Dataset<Row> sqlDF = sparkSession.sql("select * from 
                new_perf_returns where code = 'XYZ' and 
                as_of = date_format('2016-11-01','yyyy-MM-dd')");
```

I get the same error.

Comment: I further troubleshooted. if I use the between function such as Dataset<Row> sqlDF = sparkSession.sql("select * from 
                new_perf_returns where code = 'XYZ' and 
                as_of between date_format('2016-11-01','yyyy-MM-dd') and date_format('2016-11-30','yyyy-MM-dd')");It works. It means that it doesn't like = operator. Should I use like this Dataset<Row> sqlDF = sparkSession.sql("select * from 
                new_perf_returns where code = 'XYZ' and 
                as_of === date_format('2016-11-01','yyyy-MM-dd')");

Comment: date_format is a spark function not oracle function